# Pytest-Flask Cannot import name 'create_app'

Tags: python, flask, pytest

Trying to run a basic functional test with pytest-flask but keep getting this error:

```
    tests/conftest.py:2: in <module>
    from learning_flashcards import create_app
E   ImportError: cannot import name 'create_app'
```

Here is my directory structure:

```
.
├── Procfile
├── __pycache__
├── config.py
├── learning_flashcards
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── app.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── db.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   │   └── style.css
│   ├── templates
│   └── views.py
├── learning_flashcards.egg-info
│   ├── PKG-INFO
│   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   ├── requires.txt
│   └── top_level.txt
├── manage.py
├── migrations
│   ├── README
│   ├── alembic.ini
│   ├── env.py
│   ├── script.py.mako
│   └── versions
├── requirements
│   ├── common.txt
│   ├── dev.txt
│   └── runtime.txt
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
├── tests
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── conftest.cpython-36-pytest-5.4.3.pyc
│   │   ├── test_data.cpython-36-pytest-5.4.3.pyc
│   │   └── test_site.cpython-36-pytest-5.4.3.pyc
│   ├── conftest.py
│   ├── test_data.py
│   └── test_site.py
└── venv
```

And here is my conftest.py file:

```
import pytest

from learning_flashcards import create_app

@pytest.fixture
def app():
    app = create_app()
    return app
```

Have tried various ways of exploring the import system (from .learning_flashcards, from .learning_flashcards.learning_flashcards, etc.), have also investigated the init file to see if it is not creating the app instance correctly, but it looks to be fine. App runs on local server but can't get test suite to work.

Here's **init**.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

import learning_flashcards.views
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres@localhost/flashcards'

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

And app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from models import db

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    db.init_app(app)

    @app.route('/')
    def learning_flashcards():
        return "Hello World!"



    POSTGRES = {
        'user': 'postgres',
        'pw': 'password',
        'db': 'my_database',
        'host': 'localhost',
        'port': '5432',
    }
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://%(user)s:%(pw)s@%(host)s:%(port)s/%(db)s' % POSTGRES

    return app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    app.run()
```

Comment: try `from learning_flashcards.app import create_app` and delete all `.pyc` files

Comment: same error comes up... am i supposed to recompile first? not sure how to do that. Edit: also recompiled but same error. running the command py.test in the root directory on osx but also tried:                                                                                                     python3 -m pytest
pytest

Comment: update: this worked. Had to add ```from learning_flashcards.app``` to both test file and conftest.py. Thanks!